# Memory allocation example by Stephen Kochan

Tags: objective-c

In his book, consider this code from Chapter 7, in a non-ARC environment:

```
Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *sum=[[Fraction alloc] init],*sum2;
int i, n=5, pow2=2;

[sum setTo: 0 over: 1]; 

for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
[aFraction setTo: 1 over: pow2];
sum2 = [sum add:aFraction]; // Comment 1
[sum release];
sum = sum2; // Comment 2
pow2 *=2;
}

[sum doSomething];
[sum release];
```

Can someone confirm my understanding is correct:

Note, Comment 1 - I know this `add` function is returning an alloc'd object, f.y.i, so `sum2` now owns an object (a non-autoreleased object) (as per other code in the book)

Question, Comment 2 - We released `sum` - so does `sum` simply persist as an empty pointer, until it is "assigned" to `sum2` ? Since `sum2` owns an object, when `sum2` is assigned a *new* alloc'd object at Comment 1, `sum` remains the sole owner of the object from the prior iteration, and a `[sum2 release]` is not necessary. When `[sum release]` occurs just above Comment 2, that object finally disappears, to ultimately be replaced by a new one in that same loop. Is this the correct interpretation?

Finally, though we never release `sum2`, since `sum=sum2` by doing a `[sum release]' at the very end, this is leaving the program with no memory leak, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRT to comment 1:

```
sum2 = [sum add:aFraction];
```

This call implies the return of an autorelease'd object.  This is by convention; only methods starting with `init` or called `new` should return a non-autoreleased object, all others are supposed to be autoreleased.

WRT to comment 2:

No after `sum` is released the pointer to it remains non-`nil`, however what it points to is a potentially free'd object.  Accessing the object via this reference will cause issues at some point; possibly immediately.  The pointer doesn't *own* anything; the concept of ownership is at a method- or class-level.  For example

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
Foo *foo2 = foo;
Foo *foo3 = foo2;
```

The method *owns* `foo`, and just happens to have three references to the same object. This is OK, as long as you remember this and only `release` the object once (you can use any of the references to `release` the object).